# if $f$ is such that : $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2f(x) \mathrm{d}x \leq M$ then $f = O(x^3)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, asymptotics

I am wondering if the following is true :

> Let $f$ be a positive piecewise continuous function such that : $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2f(x) \mathrm{d}x \leq M$$
>   Then can we conclude that $f = O(x^{-3})$ at $\pm \infty$ ?

I tried to see if a proof by contradiction works here yet what I am doing doesn't lead anywhere :

Suppose there is a stricly increasing sequence $(x_n)$ such that : $f(x_n) \geq \frac{1}{x_n^2}$. But then what to do ? Since we can just say this on single point it's impossible to integrate (since it's discrete)..

Thank you !

Comment: Should that be $O(x^{-3})$ in the problem?

Comment: This is wrong. You can construct a function $f$ with $f(n)=e^n$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$, that still has $\int x^2f(x)dx<\infty$.

Comment: You can probably make this true by adding some smoothness assumption and some integrability of the derivative. Assuming that $f\in C^1$ and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f'(y)|\, dy<\infty$ should be enough.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thank you for the comment, this is interesting. The condition of absolute integrability of $f'$ is there so that $\lim_{ x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$ right ? but then how to prove your claim ? Ty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no. 
Let $f(x)=1/n^2$ in $[n,n+1/n^a]$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}^+$ and zero  otherwise then 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2f(x)\,dx =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}\int_n^{n+1/n^a}x^2dx=\frac{1}{3}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} ((n+1/n^a)^3-n^3)\\
=\frac{1}{3}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}\cdot 
\left(\frac{3n^2}{n^a}+\frac{3n}{n^{2a}}+\frac{1}{n^{3a}}\right)$$
It follows that for  $a>1$ the RHS is convergent.

How can you modify $f$ in order to have a **positive** piecewise continuous function?

Comment: Why not just $f(x)=1$ in the interval and $a=4$ ?

Comment: What are the assumptions to get his/her result ? With $f$ continuous it works ?

Comment: @Thinking We can modify the given $f$ and get a continuous counterexample.

Comment: @zwim  Which interval?

Comment: $f(x)=1$ in $[n,n+n^{-4}]$ and zero otherwise. I don't get why you insist on taking $f(x)=n^\alpha$, did I miss something ?

Comment: Of course there are infinite counterexamples... I started from OP's remark: $f(x_n) \geq \frac{1}{x_n^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Define $f$ to be $0$ everywhere except that on $[n^{10},n^{10}+n^{-100}]$ it takes value $n^{40}$ (where $n\in \mathbb{N}$). This is piecewise constant, so in particular piecewise continuous, and we have 
$$
     \int_0^\infty x^2 f(x)\, dx < \sum_{n=1}^\infty (n^{10}+n^{-100})^2 n^{-60} < 1.
$$
However if $x=n^{10}$ then $f(x) = n^{40}$, which is not bounded by a constant times $x^3 = n^{30}$.

Answer (score 1):

If you assume that $f\in C^1$ and that $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f'(y)|\, dy<\infty, $$ then it is **almost** true. Indeed, with these assumptions the limit 
$$
\lim_{|x|\to \infty} f(x) $$ 
must exist, and so the limit of $x^2f(x)$ exists also, perhaps infinite. However, for the integral 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2 f(x)\, dx $$ 
to be finite, it is necessary that 
$$ \lim_{|x|\to \infty} x^2 f(x)=0, $$ 
that is, $f(x)=o(|x|^{-2})$. (You wanted $f(x)=O(|x|^{-3})$ which is slightly more than this).

Comment: Maybe the stronger result $f(x)=O(|x|^{-3})$ is true also. Frankly I don't know, I must admit I didn't think hard about this.